# What are the advantages of material nodes?

Tags: materials, node-editor

Applying materials and textures to a particular model, what are the relative advantages and disadvantages of applying materials and textures without nodes, and with nodes?

Comment: In cycles the only difference is usability. I find it much easier to work with a node tree than a stack of drop-down menus, but functionally they are the same.

Comment: @braasshat: Please specify: What renderer do you use? It's makes a difference between using Cycles or the blender internal render engine.

Comment: Blender internal is what I usually work with, as what I produce is for a game with its own render engine.